# appWidget stops updating/working after some time while phone is locked

Tags: java, android, multithreading, widget, android-appwidget

My widget stops updating/working after some time. I have a simple widget which displays quotes every few hours (now is set to seconds for testing), for timing it uses a separate thread.

What can be wrong? Why does it stop updating?
Thanks!

```
package com.example.napiige;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;


public class MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider {   

    String azIge;   
    static MainActivity[] ige = new MainActivity[3];


    @Override
     public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        String ig1 = context.getString(R.string.ige1);
        String ig2 = context.getString(R.string.ige2);
        String ig3 = context.getString(R.string.ige3);

        ige = new MainActivity[3];

        ige[0] = new MainActivity();
        ige[1] = new MainActivity();
        ige[2] = new MainActivity();

        ige[0].azIge = ig1;
        ige[1].azIge = ig2;
        ige[2].azIge = ig3;

        go(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);


        }
    }

    void go(final Context context, AppWidgetManager mgr, final int[] myWidgetId) {

        final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.example_appwidget);        

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                int i = 0;
                while (i < 3) {

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);

                        views.setTextViewText(R.id.igePrint, ige[i].azIge);                             

                        AppWidgetManager awManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                        awManager.updateAppWidget(myWidgetId, views);                                           

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                       i = i + 1;
                       if (i == 3) {
                       i = 0;
                    }
                } 
            }
        }).start(); 

   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're updating every few hours why not use the built in functionality to update the app widget found in AppWidgetProviderInfo, use the `android:updatePeriodMillis` to set the update time (The minimum time you can get with this is 30 minutes I believe, but it should work for you). More information can be found at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html?utm_source=Android+Weekly&utm_campaign=b32a249c8f-Android_Weekly_46&utm_medium=email

I believe the system is killing your Thread when it feels like it, it is under no obligation to keep it running.

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/preview"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/example_appwidget"
    android:configure="com.example.android.ExampleAppWidgetConfigure" 
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/example_keyguard">
</appwidget-provider>
```

Comment: You may right, I will use the default update functionality and test it on the long run. Thanks @svenoaks.

Answer (score 1):

If the device is asleep when it is time for an update, then the device will wake up in order to perform the updataion.For test-being purpose even if you call lessthan 30 minutes in `android:updatePeriodMillis` it won't update because  it reqires min 30 miintes of time o update.we can also update it manually by calling reiever and by checking the action in the `receiever` and call update method manually because `onUpdate()` metod will not call by the android